# Cannot access getters in Nuxt.js + Vuex in modules mode

Tags: vuex, nuxt.js

I'm using nuxt.js and vuex in Universal mode.

My `store/index.js` looks like this

```
export const state = () => ({})

export const mutations = {}

export const getters = {}
```

I have a `store/cart.js` file

```
export const state = () => ({
  cartOpen: false
})

export const getters = {
  cartOpen(state) {
    return state.cartOpen;
  }
}
```

In my `Header.vue`, I have this

```
<script>
import { mapGetters } from "vuex";

export default {
  name: "Header",
  computed: mapGetters({
    cartOpen: "cart/cartOpen"
  })
};
</script>
```

I have also tried this

```
  computed: {
    ...mapGetters("cart", ["cartOpen"])
  }
```

But in my vue devtools, the computed property shows `undefined`

Answer (score 0):

You can try
store/cart.js

```
export const getters = {
   GetCartOpen: state=> state.cartOpen
}
```

In the header.vue file, define

```
export default{
  data() {
   return {
    cart:false 
  };
```

and in

```
created() 
{
  this.cart = this.cartOpen // This will assign store state of cart to local cart data variable
}
```

It works for me, might work for you as well. Good luck

**OR**

this.$store.getters['cart/GetCartOpen'];